How to Clamp Player Position Correctly Within Boundary Colliders?
I am working on a Unity game where I need to keep the player character within specific boundary colliders. I want to clamp the player's position so that they cannot move outside these boundaries. However, even when the player is beyond the boundaries, the position seems to be clamped incorrectly.
The player’s position is being clamped, but it still seems to be restricted even after crossing the boundary colliders. I have set up the ClampPositionToRoad method to clamp the player's x-coordinate between the left and right boundaries, but it does not work as expected.
protected virtual void ClampPositionToRoad()
{
    float leftBoundary = leftBoundaryCollider.transform.position.x - (leftBoundaryCollider.size.x * 0.5f);
    float rightBoundary = rightBoundaryCollider.transform.position.x + (rightBoundaryCollider.size.x * 0.5f);

    Debug.Log($"Left Boundary: {leftBoundary}, Right Boundary: {rightBoundary}");

    Vector3 clampedPosition = transform.position;
    clampedPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, leftBoundary, rightBoundary);

    transform.position = clampedPosition;
}


How to turn 90 Degree left or Right when x position is clamped with boundaries ?
How ever i tried so many methods, only adding boundries but it doesnt work.
I’ve tried adjusting the boundary values and printed out the boundaries and player position using Debug.Log, but the issue persists. I also tested with hardcoded values for boundaries, but the result was the same.
How can I correctly clamp the player’s position within the boundary colliders in Unity? Are there any mistakes in my current approach, or is there a better way to handle this?
Unity Version: 2022.3.17f56
Platform: MAC
My Full code is Below, Suggest me any other changes please.
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BoxCollider leftBoundaryCollider;
    public BoxCollider rightBoundaryCollider;

    public float speedModifier = 0.05f;
    public float cameraSpeed = 0.05f;

    public Vector3 cameraRotation;
    public Vector3 cameraPosition;
    public GameObject skinnedMeshObject;
    private SkinnedMeshRenderer skinnedMeshRenderer;
    public float timeScoreMultiplier = 10f;
    public float crouchDuration = 1f;

    public float pursuerPositionOffset = 4f;

    public float initialHitSpeed = -10f;
    public float hitSpeedDecreaseSpeed = 80f;

    public LayerMask levelLayer;
    public AudioClip jumpSideClip;
    public AudioClip jumpClip;
    public AudioClip gameOverClip;
    public AudioClip crouchClip;

    public BoxCollider[] boxCollider;
    public CapsuleCollider[] capsuleColliders;

    public float mouseAndTouchMoveDistance = 80f;

    public bool enableKeyboardMovement = true;
    public bool enableMouseMovement = true;

    [SerializeField]
    protected float m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;
    protected float m_OrigGroundCheckDistance;
    protected Vector3 m_GroundNormal;
    [SerializeField]
    protected float m_JumpPower = 12f;
    [SerializeField]
    protected float stepDistance = 1.5f;
    private bool countdownFinished = false;
    public float speed = 3f;

    public int skinPrice = 1000;

    protected Animator anim;
    public AudioSource countdownSound;
    public Text CountText;
    protected float posX = 0.0f;
    protected float startTime;
    protected float jumpSpeed;
    protected bool m_Jump;
    protected Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;

    protected bool m_PreviouslyGrounded, m_IsGrounded;
    protected Collider m_Collider;
    protected Vector3 m_GroundContactNormal;

    protected bool dead;

    protected int coins;
    protected float time;
    protected bool crouching;
    protected float crouchDeltaHeight = 1f;
    protected Manager manager;

    protected float jumpMultiplier = 1f;
    protected float timeMultiplier = 1f;
    protected float coinsMultiplier = 1f;

    protected float jumpMultiplierTime;
    protected float timeMultiplierTime;
    protected float coinsMultiplierTime;

    protected AudioSource audioSource;

    protected Vector2 fp;  // first finger position
    protected Vector2 lp;  // last finger position
    protected bool swiped = true;

    protected float animForward = 0.5f;
    public bool gamemodeon = false;
    public bool cameramode = true;
    protected float hitSpeedLoc;
    [HideInInspector]

    public Transform thisTransform;

    protected bool atThreeWayJunction = false;  // Flag to check if player is at a three-way junction

    protected bool atTwoWayJunction = false;

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        thisTransform = transform;
    }

    protected virtual void Start()
    {


        hitSpeedLoc = speed;
        anim = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
        anim.applyRootMotion = false;

        m_Collider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
        m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        m_OrigGroundCheckDistance = m_GroundCheckDistance;

        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        skinnedMeshRenderer = skinnedMeshObject.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
        StartCoroutine(StartCountdown());


        leftBoundaryCollider = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("LeftBoundary").GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
        rightBoundaryCollider = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("RightBoundary").GetComponent<BoxCollider>();


    }


    IEnumerator StartCountdown()
    {

        countdownSound.Play();
        // Display "3"
        CountText.text = "3";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        // Display "2"
        CountText.text = "2";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        // Display "1"
        CountText.text = "1";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);

        // Display "Go!"
        CountText.text = "Run!";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        // Set the countdown finished flag to true
        countdownFinished = true;
        countdownSound.Stop();
        // Clear the countdown text
        CountText.text = "";
        gamemodeon = true;
        cameramode = false;
    }


    private IEnumerator SlowPlayerSpeedAndFlashCoroutine(float slowDownFactor, float duration, float flashInterval)
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0f;
        bool isVisible = true;
        float originalSpeed = speed;

        while (elapsedTime < duration)
        {
            if (skinnedMeshRenderer != null)
            {
                skinnedMeshRenderer.enabled = isVisible;
                isVisible = !isVisible;
                speed = 2.5f;
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(flashInterval);
            elapsedTime += flashInterval;
        }

        if (skinnedMeshRenderer != null)
        {
            skinnedMeshRenderer.enabled = true; // Ensure the player is visible at the end

        }

        speed = originalSpeed;

    }

    private void HandleSwipe(bool left)
    {
        if (atThreeWayJunction || atTwoWayJunction)
        {
            RotatePlayer(left);
        }
        else
        {
            MoveSide(left);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void RotatePlayer(bool left)
    {
        if (atThreeWayJunction)
        {
            float rotationAngle = left ? 90f : -90f;
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotationAngle, 0);

            // Rotate smoothly over time
            StartCoroutine(RotateOverTime(targetRotation, 0.5f));

            // // Ensure movement aligns with new rotation
            // StartCoroutine(EnsureMovementAfterRotation(rotationAngle));
        }
        if (atTwoWayJunction)
        {
            if (left)
            {

                float rotationAngle = 90f;
                Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotationAngle, 0);

                // Rotate smoothly over time
                StartCoroutine(RotateOverTime(targetRotation, 0.5f));
            }

        }
    }

    private IEnumerator RotateOverTime(Quaternion targetRotation, float duration)
    {
        Quaternion startRotation = thisTransform.rotation;
        float elapsedTime = 0f;

        while (elapsedTime < duration)
        {
            thisTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, targetRotation, elapsedTime / duration);
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        thisTransform.rotation = targetRotation;
    }

    private IEnumerator HighPlayerSpeedCoroutine(float highDownFactor, float duration)
    {
        float originalSpeed = speed;
        speed *= highDownFactor;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
        speed = originalSpeed;
    }

    protected virtual void Crouch()
    {
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(crouchClip);
        anim.SetBool("Crouch", true);
        crouching = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < boxCollider.Length; i++)
        {
            boxCollider[i].size -= new Vector3(0, crouchDeltaHeight, 0);
            boxCollider[i].center -= new Vector3(0, crouchDeltaHeight / 2, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < capsuleColliders.Length; i++)
        {
            capsuleColliders[i].height -= crouchDeltaHeight;
            capsuleColliders[i].center -= new Vector3(0, crouchDeltaHeight / 2, 0);
        }

        Invoke("stopCrouching", crouchDuration);
    }

    protected virtual void stopCrouching()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Crouch", false);
        crouching = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < boxCollider.Length; i++)
        {
            boxCollider[i].size += new Vector3(0, crouchDeltaHeight, 0);
            boxCollider[i].center += new Vector3(0, crouchDeltaHeight / 2, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < capsuleColliders.Length; i++)
        {
            capsuleColliders[i].height += crouchDeltaHeight;
            capsuleColliders[i].center += new Vector3(0, crouchDeltaHeight / 2, 0);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Jump()
    {
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if (!Physics.Raycast(thisTransform.position + Vector3.up, Vector3.up, out hitInfo, 2f, levelLayer))
        {
            m_Jump = true;
            if (crouching)
            {
                CancelInvoke("stopCrouching");
                stopCrouching();
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void MoveSide(bool right)
    {
        if (m_IsGrounded)
        {
            anim.SetBool("Side", right);
            anim.SetTrigger("JumpSide");
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(jumpSideClip);
        }

        if (crouching)
        {
            CancelInvoke("stopCrouching");
            stopCrouching();
        }

        Vector3 direction = right ? thisTransform.right : -thisTransform.right;

        // Calculate new position
        Vector3 newPosition = thisTransform.position + direction * stepDistance;

        // // Apply movement without rotation
        thisTransform.position = newPosition;

        // Debugging information
        Debug.Log("Moving " + (right ? "right" : "left") + ". Direction: " + direction);
    }

    protected bool HasMouseMoved()
    {
        return (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0) || (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") != 0);
    }

    protected virtual void Update()
    {
        if (!dead && gamemodeon && !cameramode && Time.timeScale != 0)
        {


            CheckGroundStatus();

            if (animForward < 1f)
            {
                anim.SetFloat("Forward", animForward);
                animForward += Time.deltaTime * 2f;
            }
            else
                anim.SetFloat("Forward", 1f);

            if (!crouching)
                anim.SetBool("OnGround", m_IsGrounded);

            if (!m_IsGrounded)
                anim.SetFloat("Jump", m_Rigidbody.velocity.y);

#if UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS

            //Mobile Platforms movement
            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
            {
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    swiped = false;
                    fp = touch.position;
                    lp = touch.position;
                }
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                {
                    lp = touch.position;
                }
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    swiped = true;
                }
                if(!swiped)
                {
                    if ((fp.x - lp.x) > mouseAndTouchMoveDistance) // left swipe
                    {
                        // swiped = true;
                        // MoveSide(false);
                       HandleSwipe(false);
                    }
                    else if ((fp.x - lp.x) < -mouseAndTouchMoveDistance) // right swipe
                    {
                        // swiped = true;
                        // MoveSide(true);
                        HandleSwipe(true);
                    }
                    else if ((fp.y - lp.y) < -mouseAndTouchMoveDistance) // up swipe
                    {
                        if (!m_Jump)
                        {
                            swiped = true;
                            Jump();
                        }
                    }
                    else if ((fp.y - lp.y) > mouseAndTouchMoveDistance) // down swipe
                    {
                        if (m_IsGrounded && !crouching)
                        {
                            swiped = true;
                            Crouch();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
#else
            //Mouse movement
            if (enableMouseMovement)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
                {
                    swiped = false;
                    fp = Input.mousePosition;
                    lp = Input.mousePosition;
                }
                if (HasMouseMoved())
                {
                    lp = Input.mousePosition;
                }
                if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0))
                {
                    swiped = true;
                }
                if (!swiped)
                {
                    if ((fp.x - lp.x) > mouseAndTouchMoveDistance) // left swipe
                    {
                        // swiped = true;
                        // MoveSide(false);
                        HandleSwipe(false);
                    }
                    else if ((fp.x - lp.x) < -mouseAndTouchMoveDistance) // right swipe
                    {
                        // swiped = true;
                        // MoveSide(true);
                        HandleSwipe(true);
                    }
                    else if ((fp.y - lp.y) < -mouseAndTouchMoveDistance) // up swipe
                    {
                        if (!m_Jump)
                        {
                            swiped = true;
                            Jump();
                        }
                    }
                    else if ((fp.y - lp.y) > mouseAndTouchMoveDistance) // down swipe
                    {
                        if (m_IsGrounded && !crouching)
                        {
                            swiped = true;
                            Crouch();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Keyboard movement
            if (enableKeyboardMovement)
            {
                float horizontal = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
                float vertical = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");

                Vector3 m_Input = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);

                if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Horizontal") && m_Input.x < 0)
                {
                    // MoveSide(false);
                    HandleSwipe(false);
                }
                if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Horizontal") && m_Input.x > 0)
                {
                    // MoveSide(true);
                    HandleSwipe(true);
                }
                if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Vertical") && m_Input.y > 0)
                {
                    if (!m_Jump)
                    {
                        Jump();
                    }
                }
                if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Vertical") && m_Input.y < 0)
                {
                    if (m_IsGrounded && !crouching)
                    {
                        Crouch();
                    }
                }
            }
#endif

            if (m_IsGrounded)
            {
                HandleGroundedMovement(m_Jump);
            }

            speed += Time.deltaTime * speedModifier;

            if (timeMultiplierTime > 0)
            {
                timeMultiplierTime -= Time.deltaTime;
                if (timeMultiplierTime <= 0)
                {
                    timeMultiplierTime = 0;
                    timeMultiplier = 1f;
                }
            }
            if (coinsMultiplierTime > 0)
            {
                coinsMultiplierTime -= Time.deltaTime;
                if (coinsMultiplierTime <= 0)
                {
                    coinsMultiplierTime = 0;
                    coinsMultiplier = 1f;
                }
            }
            if (jumpMultiplierTime > 0)
            {
                jumpMultiplierTime -= Time.deltaTime;
                if (jumpMultiplierTime <= 0)
                {
                    jumpMultiplierTime = 0;
                    jumpMultiplier = 1f;
                }
            }

            m_Jump = false;
        }
        if (cameramode)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("Forward", 0.5f);
        }
    }

  protected virtual void ClampPositionToRoad()
{
    // Get the boundaries in world space
    float leftBoundary = leftBoundaryCollider.transform.position.x - (leftBoundaryCollider.size.x * 0.5f);
    float rightBoundary = rightBoundaryCollider.transform.position.x + (rightBoundaryCollider.size.x * 0.5f);

    // Debugging information
    Debug.Log($"Left Boundary: {leftBoundary}, Right Boundary: {rightBoundary}");

    // Clamp the player's position within the boundaries
    Vector3 clampedPosition = transform.position;
    clampedPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, leftBoundary, rightBoundary);

    // Apply the clamped position
    transform.position = clampedPosition;
}



    protected virtual void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!dead && gamemodeon)
        {
            if (!m_IsGrounded)
            {
                HandleAirborneMovement();
            }

            if (!cameramode)
            {
                // Forward movement
                Vector3 forwardMovement = thisTransform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                // Calculate new position
                Vector3 newPosition = thisTransform.position + forwardMovement;
                thisTransform.position = newPosition;

                if (leftBoundaryCollider != null  && rightBoundaryCollider != null )
                {
                    ClampPositionToRoad();
                }

            }
        }
    }



    protected virtual void CheckGroundStatus()
    {
        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        // 0.3f is a small offset to start the ray from inside the character
        // it is also good to note that the transform position in the sample assets is at the base of the character
        if (Physics.Raycast(thisTransform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.3f), Vector3.down, out hitInfo, m_GroundCheckDistance + 0.3f, levelLayer))
        {
            m_GroundNormal = hitInfo.normal;
            m_IsGrounded = true;
            //m_Animator.applyRootMotion = true;
        }
        else
        {
            m_IsGrounded = false;
            m_GroundNormal = Vector3.up;
            //m_Animator.applyRootMotion = false;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void HandleAirborneMovement()
    {
        // apply extra gravity from multiplier:
        Vector3 extraGravityForce = (Physics.gravity * 9f) - Physics.gravity;
        m_Rigidbody.AddForce(extraGravityForce);

        m_GroundCheckDistance = m_Rigidbody.velocity.y < 0 ? m_OrigGroundCheckDistance : 0.01f;
    }

    protected virtual void HandleGroundedMovement(bool jump)
    {
        // check whether conditions are right to allow a jump:
        if (jump)
        {
            // jump!
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(jumpClip);
            m_Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(m_Rigidbody.velocity.x, m_JumpPower * jumpMultiplier, m_Rigidbody.velocity.z);
            m_IsGrounded = false;
            m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("ThreeWayJunction"))
        {
            Debug.Log("exit ThreeWayJunction");
            atThreeWayJunction = false;
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("atTwoWayJunction"))
        {
            Debug.Log("exit atTwoWayJunction");
            atTwoWayJunction = false;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("ThreeWayJunction"))
        {
            Debug.Log("ThreeWayJunction");
            atThreeWayJunction = true;
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("atTwoWayJunction"))
        {
            Debug.Log("atTwoWayJunction");
            atTwoWayJunction = true;
        }
        if (!dead)
        {
            if (other.tag == "Bonus")
            {
                Bonus bonus = other.GetComponent<Bonus>();
                Transform effect = Instantiate(bonus.effect, thisTransform.position + Vector3.up * capsuleColliders[0].center.y, Quaternion.identity).transform;
                effect.SetParent(thisTransform);

                if (bonus.sound != null)
                {
                    audioSource.PlayOneShot(bonus.sound);
                }

                if (bonus.isCoin)
                {
                    coins += (int)(bonus.multiplier * coinsMultiplier);
                }
                else if (bonus.isTimeMultiplier)
                {
                    if (timeMultiplier < bonus.multiplier)
                        timeMultiplier = bonus.multiplier;
                    timeMultiplierTime += bonus.time;
                }
                else if (bonus.isCoinsMultiplier)
                {
                    if (coinsMultiplier < bonus.multiplier)
                        coinsMultiplier = bonus.multiplier;
                    coinsMultiplierTime += bonus.time;
                }
                else if (bonus.isJumpMultiplier)
                {
                    if (jumpMultiplier < bonus.multiplier)
                        jumpMultiplier = bonus.multiplier;
                    jumpMultiplierTime += bonus.time;
                }

                other.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
            }


        }

    }



    public virtual void SaveRecords()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coins", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins") + coins);
        coins = 0;
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    protected virtual void GameOver()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SlowPlayerSpeedAndFlashCoroutine(0.5f, 1f, 0.05f));
    }

    public void GoFast()
    {
        StartCoroutine(HighPlayerSpeedCoroutine(5f, 4f));
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (!dead)
        {
            //GameOver
            if (other.collider.tag != "Bonus" && (other.contacts[0].normal.z < -0.8f && other.contacts[0].normal.z > -1.2f))
            {
                bool gameOver = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < other.contacts.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (other.contacts[i].thisCollider == m_Collider)
                    {
                        gameOver = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (gameOver)
                {
                    GameOver();
                    Debug.Log("GameOver");
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}


This is a lot of code, is the error you're having only having to do with the first snippit? If not, could you only include the code that's relevant to the issue you're having? (a [mre])?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Check my answer about boundary too here . Hope it can solve your problem

One solution to this could be clamping the player position inside the boundary colliders and rotating the player by 90 degrees when hitting a boundary. This way, the character will surely stay inside the defined area and, upon hitting the borders, he will be rotated without any stop.
protected virtual void ClampPositionToRoad()
{
    float leftBoundary = leftBoundaryCollider.transform.position.x - (leftBoundaryCollider.size.x * 0.5f);
    float rightBoundary = rightBoundaryCollider.transform.position.x + (rightBoundaryCollider.size.x * 0.5f);

    Vector3 clampedPosition = transform.position;
    clampedPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, leftBoundary, rightBoundary);

    if (clampedPosition.x == leftBoundary || clampedPosition.x == rightBoundary)
    {
        RotatePlayerAtBoundary(clampedPosition.x == leftBoundary);
    }

    transform.position = clampedPosition;
}

protected virtual void RotatePlayerAtBoundary(bool atLeftBoundary)
{
    float rotationAngle = atLeftBoundary ? -90f : 90f;
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotationAngle, 0);

    StartCoroutine(RotateOverTime(targetRotation, 0.5f));

    Vector3 newDirection = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotationAngle, 0) * transform.forward;
    transform.forward = newDirection;

    Debug.Log($"Player turned {(atLeftBoundary ? "left" : "right")} at the boundary.");
}

protected virtual void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (!dead && gamemodeon)
    {
        if (!m_IsGrounded)
        {
            HandleAirborneMovement();
        }

        if (!cameramode)
        {
            Vector3 forwardMovement = thisTransform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            thisTransform.position += forwardMovement;

            if (leftBoundaryCollider != null && rightBoundaryCollider != null)
            {
                ClampPositionToRoad();
            }
        }
    }
}

